# About the Frechet derivative of a functional

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations, nonlinear-analysis, frechet-derivative

How can I compute the Frechet derivative of the functional 
$$
I(u)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\Omega} \vert \nabla u\vert ^2\ dx \ 
    + \ \int_{\Omega}\left[1-|u|^2\right]^2\ dx$$ for $u$ in a functional space with norm $\Vert u \Vert ^2=\left(  \int_{\Omega} \vert \nabla u\vert ^2\ dx + \int_{\Omega} \vert u\vert ^2\ dx \right)$. I still haven't study the Frechet derivative but I need it as soon as posible. Any advice, hint or a good reference to sea this will be appreciated. Thanks in avance.

Comment: Sorry, the notation is really confusing, $u$ is a function, I suppose. What is $\Omega$ and what does $dx$ signifies in your notation?

Comment: Yes, $u=u(x)$ is a function and you can assume that $\Omega=\mathbb{R}^N $.